# Terraform Validation Condition block Issue

Tags: validation, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to write a condition on a map variable for firewall rules. My current code works fine but the moment I do a firewall rule with policy_rule_direction = "EGRESS" it fails due to the condition continuously looking for "INGRESS". Basically if direction is INGRESS check to see if src_ip_ranges is not null and if direction is EGRESS check to see dest_ip_rangs is not null.

```
variable "rule" {
  description = ""
  default     = {}
  type = map(object({
    policy_rule_direction               = string
    match = object({
      dest_ip_ranges = list(string)
      src_ip_ranges  = list(string)
    })
  }))
  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for v in var.custom_rules : 
      v.policy_rule_direction == "INGRESS" && v.match.src_ip_ranges !=null
    ])
    error_message = "Ingress rules require a source range."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements I understood from your question are:

- All rules must have `policy_rule_direction` set to either `"INGRESS"` or `"EGRESS"`. All other values are invalid.
- For any rule that has `policy_rule_direction` set to `"INGRESS"`, it must have a non-null value for `src_ip_ranges`.
- For any rule that has `policy_rule_direction` set to `"EGRESS"`, it must have a non-null value for `dest_ip_ranges`.

I would typically implement this set of rules as a separate `validation` block for each requirement, because that allows returning a more specific error message for each case and also makes the individual `condition` expressions simpler than if trying to combine all of these rules together into one expression.

With that in mind, here's one way to meet those requirements:

```
variable "rule" {
  type = map(object({
    policy_rule_direction = string
    match = object({
      dest_ip_ranges = list(string)
      src_ip_ranges  = list(string)
    })
  }))
  default = {}

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for v in var.custom_rules :
      contains(["INGRESS", "EGRESS"], v.policy_rule_direction)
    ])
    error_message = "Each rule must have policy_rule_direction of either \"INGRESS\" or \"EGRESS\"."
  }

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for v in var.custom_rules :
      v.match.src_ip_ranges != null
      if v.policy_rule_direction == "INGRESS"
    ])
    error_message = "match.src_ip_ranges is required for all INGRESS rules."
  }

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for v in var.custom_rules :
      v.match.dest_ip_ranges != null
      if v.policy_rule_direction == "EGRESS"
    ])
    error_message = "match.dest_ip_ranges is required for all EGRESS rules."
  }
}
```

The second two rules both use [an `if` clause in the `for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements), which makes them consider only the rules with a specific value of `policy_rule_direction`.

The first rule will catch any rule whose direction is neither of the expected values, which is important because a rule with an unexpected direction will not be considered by either of the other rules.